# docker compose mount local drive

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using owncloud docker image to create my owncloud. The problem is it's storing the data inside the docker image. However, I want one of my driver ( I am using windows) to be used as data files.

```
volumes:
  files:
    driver: local
services:
  owncloud:
    volumes:
      - files:/mnt/data
```

This is what part of the docker-compose files looks like, I tried changing `files:/mnt/data` to `.:/mnt/data`. However, I started getting error when I tried to run the docker-compose.

Comment: Please post the error message to your question so we can assist you in a better way

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to use double quotes to expand `.` as the current directory:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ".:/path/inside/container/"
```